# Cordova splashscreen plugin - After upgrading to iOS 14 a black screen is quickly shown before splash screen appears

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, splash-screen

I am using cordova-plugin-splashscreen 6.0.0

It appears that the plugin is not working how it used to be on previous iOS versions. After upgrading to iOS 14, a black screen is shown very quickly before the real splash screen image is shown.

I am using only the Default 2x universal image in my config.xml:

Additional splash screen configurations are:

```
<preference name="SuppressesLongPressGesture" value="true" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="true" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="5000"/>
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you solve it? How?

Comment: Not solved by now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something changed in the way splash screens are handled in iOS 14:

The entry `<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~universal~anyany.jpg" />` is no longer being used for iPhones.

Now we have to add this entry: `<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone~anyany.jpg" />` in order to get iPhone devices covered too.

For people using only the **universal~anyany** entry (the only entry necessary in previous iOS versions): you just have to add the **iphone~anyany** entry to your **config.xml** file and you are good to go.

See example below:

`<splash src="<path to your image>/Default@2x~universal~anyany.jpg" />`

`<splash src="<path to your image>/Default@2x~iphone~anyany.jpg" />`

Obviously you also have to create another image file called **Default@2xiphoneanyany.jpg** (or png) with the resolution 1334 x 1334 pixels and put it inside your splash screen images directory.

Another thing that I noticed is that the splash screen fading effect is no longer working if the **FadeSplashScreenDuration** entry is not stated in the **config.xml** file.

So, you just have to add this line to your **config.xml** file and you will get the same default fading effect as in the previous iOS versions:

`<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="500"/>`

Answer (score 0):

I’m seeing the same thing. Also only using default 2x universal if that may have anything to do with it.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I believe Apple changed the way splash screen is managed in IOS 14. Hopefully they will fix splash screen plugin soon.